# Failed to convert date and/or time from string

Tags: sql-server, laravel, datetime, tinker

I'm having problems executing a query in Laravel's Tinker, where in DataGrip it works and in Tinker it doesn't. Follow the above queries:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Falha ao converter data e/ou hora da cadeia de caracteres. (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from [View_Boleto_Prop_Condominio] where [Unidade_lan] = 1 and [Id_Condo_lan] = 77 and [Data_pagamento] is null and [Bol_vencimento] > (convert(datetime, 2022-06-21)) and ([Especifica_boleto] like %ACORDO JUDICIAL% or [Especifica_boleto] like %ACORDO EXTRAJUDICIAL%))'
>>> BoletoPropCondominio::where('Unidade_lan', 0001)->where('Id_Condo_lan', 77)->whereNull('Data_pagamento')->where('Bol_vencimento', '>', "(convert(datetime, ".$bol_vencimento.", 121))")->where(function($query) { $query->where('Especifica_boleto', 'like', '%ACORDO JUDICIAL%')->orWhere('Especifica_boleto', 'like', '%ACORDO EXTRAJUDICIAL%');})->count();
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Falha ao converter data e/ou hora da cadeia de caracteres. (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from [View_Boleto_Prop_Condominio] where [Unidade_lan] = 1 and [Id_Condo_lan] = 77 and [Data_pagamento] is null and [Bol_vencimento] > (convert(datetime, 2022-06-21, 121)) and ([Especifica_boleto] like %ACORDO JUDICIAL% or [Especifica_boleto] like %ACORDO EXTRAJUDICIAL%))'
>>> BoletoPropCondominio::where('Unidade_lan', 0001)->where('Id_Condo_lan', 77)->whereNull('Data_pagamento')->where('Bol_vencimento', '>', "(convert(datetime, ".$bol_vencimento.", 102))")->where(function($query) { $query->where('Especifica_boleto', 'like', '%ACORDO JUDICIAL%')->orWhere('Especifica_boleto', 'like', '%ACORDO EXTRAJUDICIAL%');})->count();
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Falha ao converter data e/ou hora da cadeia de caracteres. (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from [View_Boleto_Prop_Condominio] where [Unidade_lan] = 1 and [Id_Condo_lan] = 77 and [Data_pagamento] is null and [Bol_vencimento] > (convert(datetime, 2022-06-21, 102)) and ([Especifica_boleto] like %ACORDO JUDICIAL% or [Especifica_boleto] like %ACORDO EXTRAJUDICIAL%))'
>>> BoletoPropCondominio::where('Unidade_lan', 0001)->where('Id_Condo_lan', 77)->whereNull('Data_pagamento')->where('Bol_vencimento', '>', "(convert(datetime, ".$bol_vencimento.", 105))")->where(function($query) { $query->where('Especifica_boleto', 'like', '%ACORDO JUDICIAL%')->orWhere('Especifica_boleto', 'like', '%ACORDO EXTRAJUDICIAL%');})->count();
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Falha ao converter data e/ou hora da cadeia de caracteres. (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from [View_Boleto_Prop_Condominio] where [Unidade_lan] = 1 and [Id_Condo_lan] = 77 and [Data_pagamento] is null and [Bol_vencimento] > (convert(datetime, 2022-06-21, 105)) and ([Especifica_boleto] like %ACORDO JUDICIAL% or [Especifica_boleto] like %ACORDO EXTRAJUDICIAL%))'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not quoting the *datetime* and your *string* literals. Removed the convert to datetime as it is not needed. Also *aggregate* is a reserved word, it might work but put it in brackets to be sure.

```
select count(*) [aggregate] 
from [View_Boleto_Prop_Condominio] 
where [Unidade_lan] = 1 
and [Id_Condo_lan] = 77 
and [Data_pagamento] is null 
and [Bol_vencimento] > '2022-06-21' 
and ([Especifica_boleto] like '%ACORDO JUDICIAL%' or [Especifica_boleto] like '%ACORDO EXTRAJUDICIAL%')
```